# OnTouchListener in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, ontouchlistener, ontouch

I have this layout in my fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ContenedorPrincipal">


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_default"
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<Button
    android:text="@string/next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/floatingActionButton"/>



    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relativelayoutglobal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/relativelayoutobligatorios"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="@string/obligatorios"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewirgeneral"
                    android:background="@color/naranja"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewirgeneral"
                    android:background="@color/black" />

                //Here are some textinputlayout

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/relativelayoutgeneral"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="@string/general"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewiugeneral"
                    android:background="@color/naranja"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewiugeneral"
                    android:background="@color/black" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/relativelayoutsuelo"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="@string/suelo"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewiusuelo"
                    android:background="@color/naranja"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewiusuelo"
                    android:background="@color/black" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/relativelayoutcon"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="@string/construccion"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewiucons"
                    android:background="@color/naranja"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewiucons"
                    android:background="@color/black" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/relativelayoutcomp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="@string/inmueblecompleto"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewiucomp"
                    android:background="@color/naranja"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewiucomp"
                    android:background="@color/black" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/relativelayoutamort"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="@string/amortizaciones"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewiuamort"
                    android:background="@color/naranja"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewiuamort"
                    android:background="@color/black" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

I need to react to the user swipping right or left, so, in the fragment that uses this layout, I implemented View.OnTouchListener, and overrode the OnTouch method:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if(!touching){
        Log.i("TAG", "onTouch llamado");

        int action = event.getActionMasked();

        switch (action) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                initialX = event.getX();
                initialY = event.getY();
                Log.d("TAG", "Action was DOWN");

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                float finalX = event.getX();
                float finalY = event.getY();

                Log.d("TAG", "Action was UP");

                if (initialX < finalX) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Left to Right swipe performed");
                }

                if (initialX > finalX) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Right to Left swipe performed");
                    validate();
                }

                if (initialY < finalY) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Up to Down swipe performed");
                }

                if (initialY > finalY) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Down to Up swipe performed");
                }

                initialX=0F;
                initialY=0F;
                finalX=0F;
                finalY=0F;

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                Log.d("TAG","Action was CANCEL");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                Log.d("TAG", "Movement occurred outside bounds of current screen element");
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

This way, the OnTouch method is not called. I have tried setting the OnTouchListener in each and every one of the different LinearLayout of my xml, and that way the OnTouch method is called, as long I am not touching in the space where another component (like the TextInputLayout) is. I would like the OnTouch be called everywhere in the parent layout, but still being able to use the TextInputLayout. I tried setting onTouchListener on the TextInputLayouts, but then they stop working as intended, and act like they wasn't enabled.

I would like to avoid using ViewPager because I have a lot of functionality that must be changed if I need to use that component.

How could I make the whole layout to react to OnTouch, while keeping the TextInputLayout working?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can `setOnTouchListener()` on the view you inflated in your fragment. This will ensure that `onTouch()` is called whenever user touches anywhere on the fragment. To enable your `TextInputLayout`, you can extend `TextInputLayout`  to make a custom class, override `onTouchEvent` in it, call super and return true as shown below.

```
public class MyTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {

    public MyTextInputLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);

        return true;
    }
}
```

You will then use `MyTextInputLayout` instead of `TextInputLayout` in your layout XML or wherever you inflate it. This will stop the touch event from being passed to the Fragment when user touches your `MyTextInputLayout`.

Additionally, make a custom class extending the `ViewGroup` that is on the root of your fragment XML, lets assume it to be a `LinearLayout`. The class would look like:

```
public class MyViewGroup extends LinearLayout {
    public MyViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public MyViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public MyViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        View myTextInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_text_input_layout); // Replace with your resource ID

        if (myTextInputLayout != null) {
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            myTextInputLayout.getHitRect(rect);

            if (rect.contains(rect)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

And you will obviously use the above class instead of the `LinearLayout` in your XML.

Comment: Trying, I will upvote if it works. Even if it doesn't, i appreciate your help.

Comment: Do accept the answer too if it works, if it doesn't tell me, I have another alternative. I'll edit the answer to add that.

Comment: Its not working. I get the same result, its only working if I click or swipe in an area not used by any component, but that is not what I want. For clarification, I want the TextInputLayout react if its a click on it, (for the user to write on the EditText inside of it) and OnTouch method if its a swipe, even if the swipe is over a TextInputLayout.

Comment: Ok... this was informative. Let's change our approach, will update the answer soon.

Comment: Welcome :), see if the updated answer works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, its not working. The OnInterceptTouchEvent is called always, no matter the gesture I do, swipe or click. Also, it needs a reference to the TextInputLayout id, and i think it is not proper to my case because there are more than one TextInputLayout, and also some of them are generated dinamically based on user interaction with the app (some are mandatory, which are in the xml, and some are added via a dialog which lets the user chooses which of them wants to appear).
I don't want to waste your time, Kamran. You have done more than enough to help me. I appreciate your help again.

Comment: You're welcome. I would recommend not to vote up my answer so that others can come and add an answer here.